# Rails each loop logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreach

I have a problem with my each loop. The line that prints programdetail.name and programdetail.bodypart doesn't print the value. Also do you know how can I make this loop a little bit more efficient? I want to print first 2 items with class "odd" and the other 2 with non-class. So and so forth.

```
<% @counter = 0 %>
<% @program.programdetails.each do |programdetail| %>
    <% @counter = @counter + 1 %>
    <% @counter = @counter % 3 %>
    <% if (@counter == 0)
      @counter -= 1
    end %>
    <%= '<h3 class="odd"><span class="moduleLabel"> #{programdetail.name}</span><span class="moduleDescription">#{programdetail.bodypart}</span></h3>' if @counter != 0 %>
    <%= '<h3><span class="moduleLabel">#{programdetail.name}</span><span class="moduleDescription">#{programdetail.bodypart}</span></h3>' if @counter != 0 %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use [the `cycle` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle)

Comment: I'm surprised it prints any of the values, since you're using string interpolation inside single-quoted strings. That should only work inside dobule-quoted strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cycle` helper could have worked, if you wanted odd/even combo, or over a collection:

```
<% @program.programdetails.each do |programdetail| %>

  <h3 class="<%= cycle("odd", "odd", "", "") %>
    <span class="moduleLabel"><%= programdetail.name %></span>
    <span class="moduleDescription"><%= programdetail.bodypart %></span>
  </h3>

<% end %>
```

To fix your code:

```
<% @counter = 0 %>
<% @program.programdetails.each do |programdetail| %>
  <% @counter = (@counter % 4) + 1 %>
  <h3 class="<%= ((1..2).cover?(@counter))? 'odd': '' %>">    
    <span class="moduleLabel"><%= programdetail.name %></span>
    <span class="moduleDescription"><%= programdetail.bodypart %></span>
  </h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your solution always print out "odd" class to h3 tag.

Comment: Also because the first solution prints class="" for 3 and 4th elements, the CSS got very bad. So, is there a solution to not print class="" for every 3 and 4th element?

Comment: `<h3 "<%= cycle("class='odd'", "class='odd'", "", "") %>`

Comment: @Yagiz: Have also corrected the second code. Earlier one was logically wrong.